# Altering HTML tags using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long list of HTML tags like the following:

```
<option>text 1</option>
<option>text 2</option>
```

etc...

I wish to use Notepad++ to make my list look like the following:

```
<option value="text 1">text 1</option>
<option value="text 2">text 2</option>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression?

Find: `<option>([^<]+)</option>`

Replace: `<option value="\1">\1</option>`

Then use individual find/replace so you don't accidentally clobber something you didn't intend to.

Answer (score 0):

create a macro.
this looks like a nice repeating keystroke sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a regex find/replace, try this:

```
Find: <option>([\w\s]+)</option>
Replace: <option value="\1">\1</option>
```